# How is NodeMCU's net.socket:hold() used to throttle server responses?

Tags: nodemcu

Looking at http://nodemcu-firmware.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsockethold I'm still not clear on how and when to call it:

> Throttle data reception by placing a request to block the TCP receive function. This request is not effective immediately, Espressif recommends to call it while reserving 5*1460 bytes of memory.

Does the recommendation to call it while reserving memory simply mean keeping an eye on node.heap and issuing the call when less than 5*1460 bytes are free? There is no other way I can think of "reserving" memory.

Comment: We're discussing this here: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1593

Comment: Thanks Marcel, although I'm now pretty sure that the problem I was hoping throttling would address is due to issues with the way nodemcu negotiates receive data frames within the firmware. Still, it would be good to have some clarification on these calls.